# How to uncomment multiple lines in a file using Ansible playbook

Tags: ansible

I want to uncomment multiple lines in a file using Ansible playbook.

Let's say this as a content which I need to comment out.

---

if [xxxx]; then
    echo xxxxxxxx
    exit;

### fi

These 4 lines I need to comment out using Ansible playbook.

PLease help me how I can comment out.

Comment: Please show some efforts you've made so far...

Answer (score 1):

An option would be to use [*blockinfile*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/blockinfile_module.html) if you control the content of the file. Set the BEGIN and END markers in the file. Then replace the block as you wish.

If the content of the file is not under your control you might want to try and set the markers with [*lineinfile*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/lineinfile_module.html) (use line, insertbefore, insertafter, firstmatch ...)

The best practice, however, is to use the module [*template*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/template_module.html).

---

Example of *blockinfile*

Given the file below for testing

```bash
shell> cat /tmp/test.txt
line1
line2

if [yyy]; then echo yyyyyyyyy exit;
  cmd
  cmd
fi

# if [xxxx]; then echo xxxxxxxx exit;
#   cmd
#   cmd
# fi

lineX
```

the goal is to uncomment the *if* statement. Create the [*markers*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/blockinfile_module.html#parameter-marker) first. Declare the variables

```yaml
  marker: marker_1
  path: /tmp/test.txt
  regex1: '# if \[xxxx\]; then echo xxxxxxxx exit;'
  replace1: '# if [xxxx]; then echo xxxxxxxx exit;'
  regex2: '# fi'
  replace2: '# fi'
```

Test if the *BEGIN* marker exists. If it does not exist, create the markers in the block

```yaml
    - name: "Check begin marker {{ marker }}"
      ansible.builtin.command:
        cmd: >
          grep -q '# BEGIN ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK {{ marker }}' {{ path }}
      register: checkmarker
      ignore_errors: true
      changed_when: false
    
    - block:
        - name: "Create begin marker {{ marker }}"
          ansible.builtin.replace:
            path: '{{ path }}'
            regexp: '{{ regex1 }}'
            replace: |-
              {{ '#' }} BEGIN ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK {{ marker }}
              {{ replace1 }}
        - name: "Create end marker {{ marker }}"
          ansible.builtin.replace:
            path: '{{ path }}'
            regexp: '({{ regex1 }}[\s\S]*?){{ regex2 }}'
            replace: |-
              \g<1>{{ replace2 }}
              {{ '#' }} END ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK {{ marker }}
      when: checkmarker.rc != 0
```

gives

```bash
shell> cat /tmp/test.txt 
line1
line2

if [yyy]; then echo yyyyyyyyy exit;
  cmd
  cmd
fi

# BEGIN ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK marker_1
# if [xxxx]; then echo xxxxxxxx exit;
#   cmd
#   cmd
# fi
# END ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK marker_1

lineX
```

Declare the variables

```yaml
  test_content: "{{ (test_out['content']|b64decode).splitlines() }}"

  marker_1_begin: "{{ test_content|select('regex', '^.*BEGIN.*marker_1.*$')|first }}"
  marker_1_end: "{{ test_content|select('regex', '^.*END.*marker_1.*$')|first }}"
  block_1_begin_index: "{{ test_content.index(marker_1_begin) + 1 }}"
  block_1_end_index: "{{ test_content.index(marker_1_end) }}"
  block_1: "{{ test_content[block_1_begin_index|int:block_1_end_index|int] }}"
  block_1_update: "{{ block_1|
                      map('regex_replace', block_1_regex, block_1_replace)|
                      join('\n') }}"
  block_1_regex: '^#\s(.*)$'
  block_1_replace: '\1'
```

Read and update the block

```yaml
    - name: "Read file {{ path }}"
      slurp:
        src: "{{ path }}"
      register: test_out
```

gives

```yaml
  marker_1_begin: '# BEGIN ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK marker_1'

  block_1_begin_index: '9'

  marker_1_end: '# END ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK marker_1'

  block_1_end_index: '13'

  block_1:
  - '# if [xxxx]; then echo xxxxxxxx exit;'
  - '#   cmd'
  - '#   cmd'
  - '# fi'

  block_1_update: |-
    if [xxxx]; then echo xxxxxxxx exit;
      cmd
      cmd
    fi
```

Update the block

```yaml
    - name: "Update block {{ marker }} in {{ path }}"
      ansible.builtin.blockinfile:
        path: "{{ path }}"
        marker: '# {mark} ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK {{ marker }}'
        block: |
          {{ block_1_update }}
```

gives

```bash
shell> cat /tmp/test.txt 
line1
line2

if [yyy]; then echo yyyyyyyyy exit;
  cmd
  cmd
fi

# BEGIN ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK marker_1
if [xxxx]; then echo xxxxxxxx exit;
  cmd
  cmd
fi
# END ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK marker_1

lineX
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    marker: marker_1
    path: /tmp/test.txt
    regex1: '# if \[xxxx\]; then echo xxxxxxxx exit;'
    replace1: '# if [xxxx]; then echo xxxxxxxx exit;'
    regex2: '# fi'
    replace2: '# fi'

    test_content: "{{ (test_out['content']|b64decode).splitlines() }}"

    marker_1_begin: "{{ test_content|select('regex', '^.*BEGIN.*marker_1.*$')|first }}"
    marker_1_end: "{{ test_content|select('regex', '^.*END.*marker_1.*$')|first }}"
    block_1_begin_index: "{{ test_content.index(marker_1_begin) + 1 }}"
    block_1_end_index: "{{ test_content.index(marker_1_end) }}"
    block_1: "{{ test_content[block_1_begin_index|int:block_1_end_index|int] }}"
    block_1_update: "{{ block_1|
                        map('regex_replace', block_1_regex, block_1_replace)|
                        join('\n') }}"
    block_1_regex: '^#\s(.*)$'
    block_1_replace: '\1'

  tasks:

    - name: "Check begin marker {{ marker }}"
      ansible.builtin.command:
        cmd: >
          grep -q '# BEGIN ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK {{ marker }}' {{ path }}
      register: checkmarker
      ignore_errors: true
      changed_when: false
    
    - block:
        - name: "Create begin marker {{ marker }}"
          ansible.builtin.replace:
            path: '{{ path }}'
            regexp: '{{ regex1 }}'
            replace: |-
              {{ '#' }} BEGIN ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK {{ marker }}
              {{ replace1 }}
        - name: "Create end marker {{ marker }}"
          ansible.builtin.replace:
            path: '{{ path }}'
            regexp: '({{ regex1 }}[\s\S]*?){{ regex2 }}'
            replace: |-
              \g<1>{{ replace2 }}
              {{ '#' }} END ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK {{ marker }}
      when: checkmarker.rc != 0

    - name: "Read file {{ path }}"
      slurp:
        src: "{{ path }}"
      register: test_out

    - debug:
        var: test_content
    - debug:
        var: marker_1_begin
    - debug:
        var: block_1_begin_index
    - debug:
        var: marker_1_end
    - debug:
        var: block_1_end_index
    - debug:
        var: block_1
    - debug:
        var: block_1_update

    - name: "Update block {{ marker }} in {{ path }}"
      ansible.builtin.blockinfile:
        path: "{{ path }}"
        marker: '# {mark} ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK {{ marker }}'
        block: |
          {{ block_1_update }}
```

See:

- [Example of blockinfile markers](https://ansible-config-light.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide-variables-files-markers.html#example-of-blockinfile-markers)
- [files-markers.yml](https://ansible-config-light.readthedocs.io/en/latest/annotation-tasks.html?highlight=markers#files-markers-yml)